# Replacing default routes for a resource in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

I have a resource defined like so:

```
resources :referrals, :except => [:show, :edit, :destroy]
```

and I'd like to *replace* (not just *add* a named route) a default route that Rails produces, specifically the one for the update action.

Here is my rake routes:

```
referrals    GET  /referrals(.:format)     {:action=>"index", :controller=>"referrals"}
             POST /referrals(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"referrals"}
new_referral GET  /referrals/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"referrals"}
referral     PUT  /referrals/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"referrals"}
share             /share(.:format)         {:controller=>"referrals", :action=>"new"}
special           /special(.:format)       {:controller=>"referrals", :action=>"index"}
thanks            /thanks(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"thanks"}
                  /:shortlink(.:format)    {:controller=>"referrals", :action=>"update"}
                  /:linktext(.:format)     {:controller=>"referrals", :action=>"update"}
root              /(.:format)              {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
```

I'd like either the

```
/:shortlink(.:format)
```

or

```
/:linktext(.:format)
```

to hit the update action, but *not* the

```
/referrals/:id(.:format)
```

This is to implement a form of non-password "security".  When the PUT goes to the update action, I want certain things to happen, but I don't want to require authorization to do this, and I don't want to allow easy guessing of the url based on controller name and simple low-numbered ids.

How can I fully **replace** the default route given by rails?

Comment: The ID in a route doesn't have to be the model ID, it can be any URL encoded attribute, such as a random hashed string. Doing this would save bending rails in a way it was not designed to bend.

Comment: Thanks @Douglas-F-Shearer!  I just used what you're saying by overriding the `to_param` method of Referral model to return the shortlink attribute for params in url construction instead of the model ID. Now by using a `find_by_shortlink(params[:id])` I can do what I want, while preventing the simple number ids from working

Comment: Interestingly, the `to_param` override was only necessary to make things like `referral_url` work correctly (which is certainly a good thing to be able to do). Strictly speaking, I could have done what I was asking in my question purely with my `find_by_shortlink(params[:id])` in my controller.

Comment: Yeah, `to_param` is only a nicety to save so you can type `referral_path(@referral)` instead of `referral_path(@referral.shortlink)`. Handy to know though. Glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

`resources :referrals, :except => [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]`

`match "/whatever_you_want/:variable_here" => "referrals#updated", :as=> the_link, :via=> :put`

then in your controller you will access the param with

`params[:variable_here]`

here the param is whatever you want to compare against in the db, and the path will be create like this:

`the_link_path` or `the_link_url`

the :via part will constrain the path per HTTP method so only put request will match

more info here 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html